# there are two different tables in database i want to fetch data from them in one single table in a sequence through date or time?

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['buyer_id'])){
    $buyer_id = $_GET['buyer_id'];
    $buyer_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM new_entry_table where buyer_id = '$buyer_id'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($buyer_query) > 1){

        $i = 1;

        while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($buyer_query)){

            $v_p_store = $show['per_vihicle_price'];
            $store_sum = $v_p_store + @$store_sum;
//**************************************
            $vihicle_id = $show['vihicle_id'];
            $select_vihicle = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from vihicles where id = '$vihicle_id'");$store_vihicle = mysqli_fetch_array($select_vihicle);

            $mine_id = $show['id'];
            $select_mines = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from mines where mine_id = '$mine_id'");$store_mine = mysqli_fetch_array($select_mines);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $show['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $store_vihicle['vihicle_type'] . " " . $store_vihicle['vihicle_no']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $store_mine['mine_name'] . " # " . $store_mine['mine_no']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "KG- " . $show['weight']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "RS- " . $show['price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "RS- " . $show['per_vihicle_price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "RS- " . $store_sum; ?></td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
    }
}
```

PHP I wanna fetch data from two table like from `buyer_record` and from `hr_recieve_payment`.

There are two different tables in database i want to fetch data from them in one single table in a sequence through date or time?

Comment: Sir My post is for that one buyer purchase something from me on loan iam going to add this loan into table but whenever they pay the loan iwant to show that loanPayed under the purchased prices

Answer (score 0):

first of all please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections. [please read](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

as I understand you want to fetch data from vihicles  and mines by buyer right?
in that case, you can fetch both this data in SQL where you are getting buyer information

```
$sql = "
    SELECT t.id,v.vihicle_type, m.mine_name, t.weight,t.price, t.per_vihicle_price, t.per_vihicle_price   FROM new_entry_table t 
    left join vihicles v on t.vihicle_id = v.id
    left join mines  m on m.mine_id=t.id
where t.buyer_id = '{$buyer_id}' order by t.date desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir My post is for that one buyer purchase something from me on loan iam going to add this loan into table but whenever they pay the loan iwant to show that loanPayed under the purchased prices in the same page.
the database tables are different.